# PHP: Loop on JSON?

Tags: php, json

i have the following JSON:

> {"Switches":["Auswahl1","Auswahl2","Auswahl3"],"Check_MK":["Auswahl1","Auswahl2","Auswahl3"],"Testgroup":["Auswahl1","Auswahl2","Auswahl3"],"Printer":["Auswahl1","Auswahl2","Auswahl3"],"CAD":["Auswahl1","Auswahl2","Auswahl3"]}

How do i loop each object while using PHP?

My thoughts were the following:

```
   <?php

      $jsonfile = file_get_contents('tags.json');
      echo $jsonfile . "<br><br>";
      $decode = json_decode($jsonfile);

      foreach($decode as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . $value;
      }

    ?>
```

Doesn't work..... Also

```
echo $decode[1];
```

and

```
echo $decode[1][1];
```

doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a second parameter to [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

This parameter returns associative array instead of existing object (if existing).

```
$decode = json_decode($jsonfile, TRUE);
```

This will convert your JSON decoded data into associative array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$jsonfile = file_get_contents('tags.json');
echo $jsonfile . "<br><br>";
$decode = json_decode($jsonfile);
```

now `$decode` is equivalent to:

```
$decode = new stdClass();
$decode->Switches = array();
$decode->Switches[] = "Auswahl1";
$decode->Switches[] = "Auswahl2";
$decode->Switches[] = "Auswahl3";
$decode->Check_MK = array();
...
```